# transition from position relative to absolute slowly

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu. My intention is for the menu to push the content below the dropdown when the menu is open, and for the content to return to its space vertically when the dropdown closes. I have achieved this by using position absolute when the menu is closed and position relative when it is open. The problem I am having is that upon closing the menu the content returns to its upward position faster than the menu retreats. I have tried adding transition: transform ease-in-out 1s to the position of the menu. but it doesn't change the result. how do I slow the movement of the content?

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Dropdown styles */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.7em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;
}

.arrow {
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #FF9900;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background: #1d1f24;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7em 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.1em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*dropdown button*/

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
  position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label>.arrow {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
}


/*sliding effect*/

.dropdown-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-1em);
  transition: transform ease 0.3s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown-content li {
  left: 0;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: calc(60ms * var(--delay))
}


/*Scroll Bar*/

.dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown" />
      <label for="dropdown" class="dropdown-btn" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                          <span><h2 style="margin: 0 auto; text-decoration: none;" >Select Publication</h2></span>
                          <span class="arrow"></span>
                        </label>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li style="--delay: 1;"><a>2023</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 2;"><a>2022</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 3;"><a>2021</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 4;"><a>2020</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 5;"><a>2019</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 6;"><a>2018</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 7;"><a>2017</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 8;"><a>2016</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 9;"><a>2015</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 10;"><a>2014</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 11;"><a>2013</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 12;"><a>2012</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 13;"><a>2011</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 14;"><a>2010</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 15;"><a>2009</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 16;"><a>2008</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 17;"><a>2007</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 18;"><a>2006</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class='content'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `position` cannot be animated/transitioned as it has no numerical values to be transitioned to.

Comment: Do you know a possible alternative to using position to accomplish this? @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using checkboxes in dropdowns. However, it's just my opinion. It's better to use a JavaScript trigger class for the dropdown button. Add a JavaScript onclick event handler to enhance its functionality.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Dropdown styles */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.7em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;
}

.arrow {
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #FF9900;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height:0px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background: #1d1f24;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7em 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.1em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*dropdown button*/

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown-content {
 
  max-height:200px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label>.arrow {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
}


/*sliding effect*/

.dropdown-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height:0;
  transform: translateY(-1em);
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown-content li {
  left: 0;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: calc(60ms * var(--delay))
}


/*Scroll Bar*/

.dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown" />
      <label for="dropdown" class="dropdown-btn" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                          <span><h2 style="margin: 0 auto; text-decoration: none;" >Select Publication</h2></span>
                          <span class="arrow"></span>
                        </label>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li style="--delay: 1;"><a>2023</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 2;"><a>2022</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 3;"><a>2021</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 4;"><a>2020</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 5;"><a>2019</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 6;"><a>2018</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 7;"><a>2017</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 8;"><a>2016</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 9;"><a>2015</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 10;"><a>2014</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 11;"><a>2013</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 12;"><a>2012</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 13;"><a>2011</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 14;"><a>2010</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 15;"><a>2009</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 16;"><a>2008</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 17;"><a>2007</a></li>
        <li style="--delay: 18;"><a>2006</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class='content'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I’m not understanding how this addresses the question as set - which was how to stop the content below going back to its original position too quickly.